# Linux `find` command with a -regex option doesn't work as expected

Tags: regex, linux, bash, find

I have a file `foo` in the current directory. Then I run the following commands:

1. `find . -regex 'foo'` finds nothing
2. `find . -regex 'foo.*'` finds nothing
3. `find . -regex '.*foo'` finds the file

I would expect that either of these commands should yield a positive result.

`find` command version is 4.4.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from the manual:

```
   -regex pattern
          File name matches regular expression pattern.  This is  a  match
          on  the  whole path, not a search.  For example, to match a file
          named `./fubar3', you can use the regular expression `.*bar.' or
          `.*b.*3',  but  not `f.*r3'.  The regular expressions understood
          by find are by default Emacs Regular Expressions, but  this  can
          be changed with the -regextype option.
```

The important part is: *This is a match on **the whole path**, not a search*.

So only the third regex yields the result:

```
./foo
```

Comment: Do I get it right that a proper regex for the second case would be `'\./foo.*'` then?

Comment: @SergeyPauk yes and `'\./foo'` for the first :-)

Answer (score 0):

`find` actually try to match the string `./foo` (differently from the `-name` switch) so the third pattern `-regex '.*foo'` have to works if the file `foo` have no extension.

Try to use:

```
``find . -regex '.*foo.*'``
```

And report the output.